# Return by value - error indication value

Tags: c++

Given the following simple function declaration :

```
vector<Date> getMonthArray(int month, int year);
```

As for C++ 11, I can take advantage of the MOVE semantics and return the Date vector by value without losing any performance and avoid using 'new' and 'delete'.

Problem is that ive no idea what to return if the function fails..
E.G. month or year are lower than zero

I can't return null as I could do with a pointer,
So I thought about two possibilities:

1) return an empty array
2) throw an exception

To be honest, I hate both. would love to hear some better solutions from more experienced c++ programmers.

EDIT:

So, throwing an exception really looks like the most elegant solution since it doesn't involve any documentation that user need to read in order to run the function properly (except the exception that can be thrown). Am I correct? or any other more alternatives?

Comment: Throwing an exception here is the way to go.

Comment: @rightfold: care to elaborate? How could you possibly know what is the 'right' solution for the OP in this case? Exception handling can be a tricky beast, and then there's all sorts of questions about where to check for exceptions and how exactly they should be handled. Perhaps the best thing for OPs code is to validate the input before calling getMonthArray, because they can, and then there  are other functions that rely on that validated input. My point is that without knowing OPs codebase, saying "Use exceptions" needs to come with a lot of salt.

Answer (score 1):

There are very few options:

1. Return a special value of the normal return type that indicates an error.
2. Change return to an error code (or flag) and have an output argument (either reference or pointer).
3. Return a wrapper that has both the value and an error indicator (ex. [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)).
4. Throw an exception.
5. Have arguments that can not be invalid.

Options 1 to 4 are pretty obvious.

Option 5 is not always possible, but careful choice of argument types (including enumerations) and interpretation can work in some cases.

Not knowing what your function does, here are some suggestions:

a. change the type of month & year to unsigned.
b. interpret 'month' as continuous:

```
vector<Date> getMonthArray(unsigned int month, unsigned int year) {
   year = year + month / 12;
   month = month % 12;
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If it may fail, an empty vector is not a terrible idea. One hack that people seem to like for returning error codes is to take the vector as a reference parameter, and change the return value of the function to a boolean, or an int if there are more types of return codes (can be enumerated type, too). Depending on the returned value, different conditions may hold for your vector. I think in this case, though an empty vector is fine so long as it's documented well.

Example of reference parameter, boolean return approach

```
//pre: none
//post: if month and year are valid, monthArray will contain array 
//      of months and function returns true.
//      Otherwise returns false with no guarantees on contents of monthArray
bool getMonthArray(int month, int year, vector<Date>& monthArray);
```

Example of error codes, reference parameter

```
//pre: none
//post: if month and year are valid, monthArray will contain array 
//      of months and function returns 0 for success.
//      If month is valid but year is not, returns -1
//      If month is invalid, but year is not, returns -2
//      If month and year are valid, but otherwise failed, returns -3
int getMonthArray(int month, int year, vector<Date>& monthArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, pass the vector and return a `bool` for success.

```
bool getMonthArray(std::vector<Date>* out, int month, int year);
```

In your implementation, return false if the parameters are invalid.